# how to rewrite url in java EE dynamic webproject

Tags: java, url, url-rewriting

I am new to Java and I still have many to learn.  I am currently testing something new relating to "url rewriting".

Is it possible to rewrite

1.
`localhost:7080/Library/admin/CategoryController?action=new`
to
`localhost:7080/Library/admin/category/**`

2.
`localhost:7080/Library/admin/CategoryController?action=listCategory`
to
`localhost:7080/Library/admin/categories`

3.
`localhost:7080/Library/admin/CategoryController?action=edit&catId=1`
to
`localhost:7080/Library/admin/category/1`

I use Servlet, JSP on Apache Tomcat server and Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just have to setup some directives with url-patterns

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CategoryController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Library/admin/category/*</url-pattern>
  <url-pattern>/Library/admin/categories/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Might be that you have to define it like this instead (some application servers are not handling more than one url-pattern per servlet-mapping, others don't want multiple mappings per servlet...

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CategoryController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Library/admin/categories/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CategoryController</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Library/admin/category/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Hope this helps.